# Prove that $f(x)=x^{3} + 2x^{2}+ 3x + 5$ has a root in the in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ (The 13-adics)

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

Prove that  $f(x)=x^{3} + 2x^{2}+  3x + 5$ has a root in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ (The 13-adics).

EDIT: NOTE: I HAD A TYPO WITH THE POLYNOMIAL'S COEFFICIENT!!!.

QUESTION: Prove that $f(x)=x^{3} + 3x^{2}+  3x + 5$ has a root in the in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$. Then find the first two terms of the succession

My attempt: Using Hensel's lemma, we obtain that $f(2)$ has a solution mod 13 and is not congruent to 0 when evaluated in $f´(2)$. Thus it has a root in the 13-adics.

Now lets find the second term of the sequence $(2, a_1, a_2, ...)$. By Hensel's Lemma, $a_1 \equiv2$ mod 13. Then $a_1= 2+13t$., Then when evaluating $f(2+13t)$ and solving for t in Wolfram, we get that $t \equiv 5$ mod 13. thus $a_1 = 2+ 13(5) = 67$.

My question is, how do I construct the sequence that the problem requires?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The polynomial has no root in the integers mod $13$, and thus no root in the $13$-adics.  Are you sure you have the question right?

Comment: Substitute $X=x+1$, then we need a root in $\Bbb Z_p$, $p=13$, for $$X^3+4\ .$$In particular, taking it modulo $p$ we have a root of $X^3+4$ in the finite field $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p$. This is not the case. (Which is exactly the source of the problem?)

Comment: Thanks, I don´t understand how do you get $X^{3} + 4 $

Comment: Here may be the problem with the question. In some languages the word corresponding to "prove" is used to mean "test" (think of the English word "probe"). I think Spanish, which looks like it might be the OP's first language ("cero"), is one such case. We can surely _test_ whether this equation has a solution, and we find it fails.

Comment: oohhh ok thanks. I don´t get the previous substitution though

Answer (score 2):

Suspecting that @OscarLanzi is correct about a mis-translation: let's *test* whether $x^3+3x^2+3x+4=0$ has a root in $\mathbb Z_{13}$. We first check in $\mathbb Z/13$, both for existence or not. As @Dan_Fulea observes (which is the kind of thing to hope for if there'd be a truly-human-understandable computation here), since $(x+1)^3=x^3+3x^2+3x+1$, the equation can be rearranged to $(x+1)^3+4=0$. Some small tricks to avoid computation: this is asking whether $-4$ is a cube mod $13$. Equivalently, is $4$ a cube? Since $4$ is a square, if it were also a cube, it'd be a sixth power (!). Since $(\mathbb Z/13)^\times$ is cyclic of order $13-1=12$, $-1$ is the only sixth power other than $1$, and $-1\not=4$ mod $13$. So there's no solution mod $13$...

EDIT: if there were a solution in the p-adic integers $\mathbb Z_{13}$, it would give a solution in $\mathbb Z_{13}/(13\cdot \mathbb Z_{13})\approx \mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z$. (Yes, this isomorphism needs a little proof...)

Comment: Thanks Paul! Does this solve the question for the p-adics??? It certainly get the answer for "usual" modular arithmetic.