# Find the invers of $4 \in \mathbb{Z}_5$ (The 5-adic integers)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to solve this question, however I don´t seem to have the correct expression of the inverse to solve the remaining part:

QUESTION: Find the inverse of 4 in $\mathbb{Z}5$. Use your answer to find an $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $4m$ is congruent to 1 mod ($5^4$).

My attempt: I need to find a $k$ such that $4k=1$. Note that $4=3+1$, then using the geometric series for $1/(1-x)$, we have taht $1/4 = 1-3 + 3^2 - 3^3 ...$ which is a 5-adic convergent series.

Now: I Don´t seem to understand how this procedure will help me in the solution of the second part. or weather this is the $m$ that I needed to find.

Anything helps. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is $1-3+9-27+81-\cdots$ convergent in the 5-adics?

Comment: I find it a bit upsetting that you (I assume, although under a different user name) have asked this question before, not responded to any comments (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4453840/96384), and then also changed a different question of yours to this question, then deleted that one (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453066/) but also reposted the original question from there (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4454316/96384). Downvote, voting to close (both questions are very poor and have not been improved in spite of several comments), and flagging for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$ \frac{1}{4}= 4+ 3\cdot\frac{5}{1-5}$$

Comment: Also useful might be $-\frac34=3-\frac34\cdot5$; then $\frac14=1-\frac34$